# Hooking up a PHP function to an AJAX request: What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

The callback message is 0 and I can't figure out why.

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) as closely as possible, but I'm obviously missing something.

In Network on Google Chrome, each time I click the button that triggers the form to submit, I see that `admin-ajax.php` is being invoked and the status is 200.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<form method="POST" action="member-update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- ... bunch of inputs and stuff in here -->
</form>
```

```php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$tm = new TeamManager();
add_action('wp_ajax_member-update', 'member_update');
function member_update() {
    echo json_encode("TEST ... ");
}
```

```js
jQuery('.member-update-button').click(function () {
    var parentForm = jQuery(this).closest('form');
    var postData = parentForm.serializeArray();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: {
            action: 'member_update',
            postData: postData
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (retmsg) {
            alert(retmsg); // test for now
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error"); // test for now
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you told JS to expect json, but you've got max error reporting/display errors on in PHP. that means **ANY** php warnings/errors will become part of the output, and be seen as a json syntax error.

Comment: where are you `echo` anything? in `member_update()`??? If yes then where are you calling `member_update()` function?

Comment: just a shot in the dark, but shouldn't it be `data: {action: 'wp_ajax_member-update', postData: postData},` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your action hook has the wrong name `wp_ajax_member-update` and your action is called `member_update`

So, your PHP code should look like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_member_update', 'member_update');
function member_update() {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
    die();
}
```

An Ajax callback always needs to end with a `die()` statement in WordPress.