# Still failing to figure out what I'm doing wrong about making a PHP function handle an AJAX request in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

After literally hours of trying to hook up a function to handler AJAX requests through WordPress's API, I am still coming short. I've gone back to basic by trying a basic test

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_member_update', 'member_update' );

    function member_update ( )
    {
        echo $_POST['testvariable'];
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'member_update',
            'testvariable': 1234
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response); // expected: 1234
        });
    });
</script>
```

and even this is returning Status Code 200 and Response 0. What am I missing? I'm perfectly following [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) as far as I can tell.

Comment: `$POST` should be `$_POST`. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @Maximus2012 Still doesn't work after update

Comment: use firebug to check if value is being posted

Comment: To add to @Dagon 's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412353/how-to-find-whether-ajax-request-successfully-send-by-fire-bug-add-on

Comment: What is the value of `ajaxurl` for the jQuery code ?

Comment: Where are you setting your `add_action` code? Because the problem there seems to be that you are setting it in your page and your page won't be called when using `ajaxurl`. Try setting it in your theme's `functions.php` and that why, it should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hooking up a PHP function to an AJAX request: What am I missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459542/hooking-up-a-php-function-to-an-ajax-request-what-am-i-missing)

Comment: @Mindastic Thanks! That was my problem ...

Comment: Cool, i will add it as an actual answer.

Comment: Also note the documentation's comments about calling `wp_die()` in your ajax callback to properly terminate the request to send a proper response.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting your `add_action` code in your page, this action won't be called since you are using `ajaxurl` and it usually goes to `wp-load.php`. You should define your action in your theme's `functions.php` code and that will make it be available all over the site (as well as for `AJAX` requests).